# i can't use EF 6 with net 4.0 in an existing project. In a new one in the same solution I can do it

Tags: entity-framework

I have a project that is was created in VS2010 in .net 4.0, and has an advanced develop.

Now I have use VS2013 and I would like to use EF 6.0 instead of EF 4.4, so I install EF 6 nuget in the project that is my repository and I try to create the edmx.

In the wizard, in one of the steps, show two options, select EF 6.0 that is disabled and EF 5.0 that is enabled. It says me that I can't select EF 6.0 because I have a reference to the EntityFramework.dll.

So I delete the reference and I try again, in this case I can select EF 6, but the edmx can't be display because there are a difference in a axml file. The dll version of EntityFramework is 4.0.

In the same solution, to make tests, I create a new project, by default is net 4.5, but I change the target. Then I install EF 6.0 this project and I try to create the edmx model. In this case I am not asked about the version of EF, directly create the model and the version of the entityFramwork dll is 6.0. If I edit the edmx file with the xml editor, I can see that the version of the model is v3, so is the version for EF6.

In the project that I has problems, I think that I clean all, I delete all the references in the project, I delete the package folder in my solution and also I delete de package config file in my project. But I am not be able to use EF 6 in this project. Also I clean my config file of the project.

That is why I have doubt if there are some problems if I use a project created in VS2010 and I open it with V2013.

the problem seems to be that in somewhere the project store information about the version of EF and use this version, but I don't know where is saved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you read this post.

[Upgrading to EF6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469466)

It have all the steps you need to update to EF6